# Why doesn't the primary key field exist in a MySQL database when creating a table?

Tags: php, mysql, database

The exact error I keep seeing is:

> Key column 'alarmID' doesn't exist in table

alarmID is my primary key field.

Here is the code I have:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS alarms (
    alaramID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (alarmID),
    Title CHAR(30),
    Description TEXT,
    DT DATETIME
    )";
```

Note: I am coding in PHP.

Comment: put primary key last in your statement

Comment: Your typing is wrong. AlarmID

Comment: check the spelling of alaramid and alarmid what you have mentioned in database and what you are retrieving is same????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS alarms (
    alaramID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (alaramID),
    Title CHAR(30),
    Description TEXT,
    DT DATETIME
    )";
```

**alaramID**

Answer (score 0):

The primary key in your table is `alaramID` and note the error its `alarmID`.So correct the spelling in the query like this

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS alarms (
    alaramID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (alaramID),
    Title CHAR(30),
    Description TEXT,
    DT DATETIME
    )";
```